# Calculus (Derivatives) prove the given question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two continuous and differentiable functions defined on the interval $[0,2]$. Suppose $f(0)>g(0)$ and $f(1)<g(1)$, show that there exists a number $u$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(u)=g(u)$. Suppose further that $f(2)>g(2)$. Show that there is a number $w$ in the interval $(0,2)$ such that $f'(w)=g'(w)$. (Hint: consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.)

I haven't really made any progress with this question. I did try applying the Intermediate value theorem, Rolle's theorem and the Mean value theorem but I'm not very sure how to go about it also I don't get why $h(x)$ would be $f(x) - g(x)$. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: `I don't get why h(x) would be f(x) - g(x)` $h(0) \gt 0$ and $h(1) \lt 0$ and $h(2) \gt 0\,$, then $\;\cdots$

Comment: How can we prove there exists a point such that  h(u) = 0?

Comment: In your own words: `applying the Intermediate value theorem`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!  What about the second part of the question? I think I need to prove h(0) = h(2)

Comment: No, all you need to prove is that there exist $a \in (0,1)$ and $b \in (1,2)$ such that $h(a)=h(b)\,$.

Comment: Any hint as to how I can go about doing that?

Comment: By the IVT, there must exist an $a \in (0,1)$ such that $h(a) = h(1) / 2\,$. Same for $b \in (1,2)\,$.

Answer (score -1):

Since the function f(x) is first increasing and then decreasing we get that it must intersect g(x) somewhere between 0 and 1. Also it becomes a monotonous function in between 0 and 2 hence there must be at least one point where the derivates(slopes) are equal hence the result